# modifier placement: Extensive and entertaining . .

Tags: modifiers, dangling-modifier

Is the following sentence correct and natural?

> **Extensive and entertaining,** literary scholars have noted that many of the tales can be thought of as the seeds from which different genres of literature were borne into the modern era.

Comment: Yes, it's fine. But note that this is a highly stylised *literary / poetic* construction (the "fronted" adjectival element ***extensive and entertaining*** actually modifies following *[many of] **the tales***, in case that's not obvious). Imho this is Off Topic "writing advice", though.

Comment: It looks like a misplaced modifier from a textbook perspective.

Comment: ...Your ***borne** into the modern era* strikes me as even more "hi-falutin". Initially I assumed a spelling mistake (for ***born = given birth to***, not ***borne = carried***). I'd definitely avoid that one! But syntactically, your text is perfectly valid.

Comment: "Extensive and entertaining" is a modifier at the embedded-clause level. But it is extracted to the main clause. Is it correct in current English?

Comment: Are there other examples?

Comment: If you're trying to pass a "learner's test", you should assume the text is ***not*** valid, because according to simple pedantic rules of grammar, the "subject" should come ***immediately*** after the fronted adjectival. Since it's not the *scholars* who are "extensive and entertaining", it's "invalid". But that's just simplified rules for teaching beginners. Actual native Anglophones (especially, competent *literary* types) can and do break such rules all the time.

Comment: More examples in the earlier question [Dangling modifiers](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/221539/dangling-modifiers). And doubtless several other questions - this is a hoary old chestnut, but in any given context any *specific* "dangling participle" might be anything from a terrible mistake to a literary *tour de force*. In your case, it's closer to the latter, but that really is a matter of style advice, not basic syntax.

Comment: ...but on that "style advice" front, I will just say that what makes your *specific* example more syntactically acceptable is that the "unwanted target" noun phrase *(**literary scholars**)* noun phrase is itself part of a clause *(literary scholars have noted that)* which can be completely discarded. As it happens, dropping that clause doesn't significantly affect the meaning (anyone who made the assertion that follows would count as a "literary scholar", including the author, so we don't really need to be told *who* has made this observation).